# Vue.js + Trigger only one event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have the below dropdown created using li and within the dropdown i want to provide the delete functionality as well. If 'X' is clicked the record must be deleted.
However when i click on 'X' it also triggers 'changeFilter' which is also inside the same li. is there a way i can prevent the 'changeFilter' trigger?

[image]
Below is the code -

```
<ul>
            <li v-on:click="createNew">Create new Filter</li>
            <li v-for="item in filters.entities" v-on:click="filter.changeFilter(item.id,item.name)">{{ item.name }}<div title="Delete filter" v-on:click="delete(item.id)">x</div></li>
        </ul>

//Inside js file 

delete: (itemId) => {
                    var result = window.parent.Xrm.WebApi.deleteRecord('ice_filters', itemId.toString());
                   
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out to add the [`stop`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers) modifier to stop the event propagation from child to parent element :

```html
<div title="Delete filter" v-on:click.stop="delete(item.id)">x</div>
```

Comment: Helpful Link -> [Event Modifier Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers)